# New to Scrapy - INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler

I am new to Scrapy but spending massive effort on it the last days. However, I still fail at the basics.

I am trying to crawl the following website: https://blogabet.com/tipsters
My objective is to download all Links to the userprofiles. For instance, https://sabobic.blogabet.com/

When I am using scrapy shell, I can extract the specific xpath. But when I try to use a script and start it with "scrapy crawl ....". I am always getting no results. INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)

What is wrong in my code?

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Request

class BlogmeSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'blogme'


    def start_request(self):

        url = "https://blogabet.com/tipsters/?f[language]=all&f[pickType]=all&f[sport]=all&f[sportPercent]=&f[leagues]=all&f[picksOver]=0&f[lastActive]=12&f[bookiesUsed]=null&f[bookiePercent]=&f[order]=followers&f[start]=0"

        headers={
            'Accept': '*/*',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,pl;q=0.8,de;q=0.7',
            'Connection': 'keep-alive',
            'Host': 'blogabet.com',
            'Referer': 'https://blogabet.com/tipsters',
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36',
            'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
        }

        yield scrapy.http.Request(url, headers=headers)



    def parse(self, response):
        username = response.xpath('//*[@class="e-mail u-db u-mb1 text-ellipsis"]/a/@href').extract()
        yield {'username': username}
```

Comment: I think you just need to change start_request to start_requests

Comment: Ui, jep. That was the mistake. Thanks :)